# Errors while Compiling in Visual C++ 2008, after installation of MS Platform SDK

Tags: visual-c++, platform-sdk

I was using OpenCV and after I installed Microsoft Platform SDK to work with OpenGL these errors are showing up when trying to compile my opencv project.

```
1>d:\program files\microsoft platform sdk for windows server 2003 r2\include\winnt.h(2645) : error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function '_interlockedbittestandset' not allowed
1>        d:\program files\microsoft platform sdk for windows server 2003 r2\include\winnt.h(2642) : see declaration of '_interlockedbittestandset'
1>d:\program files\microsoft platform sdk for windows server 2003 r2\include\winnt.h(2651) : error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function '_interlockedbittestandreset' not allowed
1>        d:\program files\microsoft platform sdk for windows server 2003 r2\include\winnt.h(2648) : see declaration of '_interlockedbittestandreset'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution: http://stefanobolli.blogspot.com/2010/10/compiler-error-c2733-second-c-linkage.html

Comment: Your solution didn't help me. I'm using VS 2005 and tried Windows SDK v6.0A and v7.0A. Still looking for solution

Comment: @geotavros: did you check the other solution?

Answer (score 1):

[This solution](http://blog.assarbad.net/20120425/annoyance-in-the-windows-sdk-headers/) solved my issue.

Take note that you *must* ensure that `intrin.h` does not get accidentally included (e.g. by some other header file you use) *before* this fix below.

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1400
//  Following 8 lines: workaround for a bug in some older SDKs
#   pragma push_macro("_interlockedbittestandset")
#   pragma push_macro("_interlockedbittestandreset")
#   pragma push_macro("_interlockedbittestandset64")
#   pragma push_macro("_interlockedbittestandreset64")
#   define _interlockedbittestandset _local_interlockedbittestandset
#   define _interlockedbittestandreset _local_interlockedbittestandreset
#   define _interlockedbittestandset64 _local_interlockedbittestandset64
#   define _interlockedbittestandreset64 _local_interlockedbittestandreset64
#   include <intrin.h> // to force the header not to be included elsewhere
#   pragma pop_macro("_interlockedbittestandreset64")
#   pragma pop_macro("_interlockedbittestandset64")
#   pragma pop_macro("_interlockedbittestandreset")
#   pragma pop_macro("_interlockedbittestandset")
#endif
```

Comment: you should include the gist of what the solution is instead of simply providing a link.